# Too few arguments through laravel custom request class

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-validation

I have added a custom request class for validate data upon creating a new tenant in the database. For some reason though I am getting the following error:

This is my custom request class: `Too few arguments to function App\\Http\\Requests\\CreateTenantRequest::Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\{closure}(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected` on line 51 which is where the closing bracket is for the message() function

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

class CreateTenantRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        $product_id = $this->get('product_id');

        return [
            'product_id' => 'required|exists:products,id|numeric',
            'name' => 'required|string|max:50',
            'email' => ['required',
                Rule::unique('tenants')->where(function($query) use ($product_id) {
                    return $query->where('product_id', $product_id);
                })
            ],
            'reseller_user_id' => 'numeric',
            'user_id_from_company' => ['required',
                Rule::unique('tenants')->where(function($query) use ($product_id) {
                    return $query->where('product_id', $product_id);
                }),
                'max:255'],
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'user_id_from_company.unique' => 'The user ID already exists for this product',
        ];
    }
}
```

Below is the actual function in the controller which calls the validation:

```
public function createTenant(CreateTenantRequest $request) {
    $request->validate();
    return 'valid!';
}
```

Comment: can you please where you are exactly getting error?

Comment: try again after commenting `$request->validate();` and see what happens.

Comment: Ah yeah, commenting out $request->validate() fixed it :) I did not know it would automaticly validate the request. Thanks! :D

Comment: If you add this as an anwser i will mark it as the solution @VibhaChosla

Comment: @MichaelGuimaraes I think the actual correct answer is further down. You just forgot the "d" in validated, which others have noted. I came here with the same silly mistake, but had to scroll down. You don't want to remove the validation if you can help it. If this is the case, can you switch the "correct" answer to the other one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove `$request->validate()` this from your controller.

Comment: Is the $request considered `validated()` by the time it gets to the controller?

Comment: @RizaKhan no. Note the answer below is the best one. This answer just removes the validation, instead of correcting the typo.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem before, in my case I still want to validate the data. There's a reason why you want to validate and wrote the Form Request class in the first place, maybe you want to reconsider to keep this line instead of removing it from your Controller.
the issue is on the command $request->**validate**();
in controller what you want to use is $request->**validated**(); then it will return you the data which then you can assign it to a variable, if the validation fails it will redirect you back to the previous page where the data is input. Basically you can replace your line

```
$request->validate();
```

to

```
$validatedData = $request->validated();
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want call validate() inside controller you can add this line

```php
   $validated = $request->validated();
```

**When you assign a variable, the validator in in controller works correctly;**